# Memory leak in |NSArray objectEnumerator|?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, memory-management

The following thread explains how to find the screen that currently contains the mouse cursor:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/104529-current-mouse-screen.html

```
- (NSScreen *)currentScreenForPointUsingEnumeration:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    NSEnumerator *screenEnumerator = [[NSScreen screens] objectEnumerator];
    NSScreen *screen;
    while ((screen = [screenEnumerator nextObject]) && !NSMouseInRect(aPoint, screen.frame, NO));

    return screen;
}
```

I have this running on every mouse movement.

Unfortunately, using the "Allocations" feature in Xcode's Instruments tool, the code above shows many allocs of `NSFastEnumeration`.

No "leaks" are showing up in the analyser, but the alloc count keeps going up and never decreases. The app's overall memory usage also continues to go up.

A similar function using a `for(...)` loop does not have the same issue.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance here? Or is it something I shouldn't worry about?

EDIT:

By the way, trying `[[[NSScreen screens] objectEnumerator] autorelease]` crashes the app and completely locks up my mouse. Unable to click or otherwise figure out a way to quit the app or Xcode. Requires OS X restart. So don't do that.

Comment: By “Xcode's analyser tool”, do you mean Instruments? Instruments is very different from the Clang Static Analyzer, and the static analyzer can't detect private implementation-detail objects piling up at run time, since run time hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Right, the "Allocations" tool of Instruments. I'll edit the question.

Comment: `objectEnumerator` does not return an object that you own; you can tell this by its name. As such, sending `autorelease` to that object is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do to improve the performance here?

I'm not sure why you think there is a performance problem.  The analyser is showing no leaks, so unless it is buggy (not impossible these days, unfortunately), there probably is not a leak.

If you wrap the code in an autorelease pool, the `NSFastEnumerations` should get deallocated.

Comment: From the question: “… the alloc count keeps going up and never decreases.” This is not a “leak” in the strict sense, but it is a memory-usage problem. [You can use Instruments to detect it](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/), which I think is what the questioner did (though he erroneously calls it the “analyser”).

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try; not sure which will help, or if they'll help at all.

One, use the actual fast enumeration syntax:

```
for( NSScreen * screen in [NSScreen screens] ){
    if( NSMouseInRect(aPoint, screen.frame, NO) ){
        return screen;
    }
}
```

Or wrap this in your own autorelease pool to help the created array and enumerator objects get deallocated as soon as possible.

```
NSScreen *screen = nil;
@autoreleasepool{
    NSEnumerator *screenEnumerator = [[NSScreen screens] objectEnumerator];
    while ((screen = [screenEnumerator nextObject]) && !NSMouseInRect(aPoint, screen.frame, NO));
    [screen retain];    // Ensure screen sticks around past return; only under MRR
}
return [screen autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using blocks, and/or wrap it up in autorelease pool eg :

```
__block NSScreen *retVal = nil;
[[NSScreen screens] enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent 
     usingBlock:^(Screen *scrn, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
         if (NSMouseInRect(aPoint, scrn.frame, NO)) {
           retVal = scrn;
           *stop = YES;
     }];
return retVal;
```